# React Axios create multiple request from one action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, get, axios

I have this scenario, a user selects a team in a dropdown, this sends a request to an endpoint

```
  const selectHomeTeamStat = evt => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    getStats(leagueId, value, 'home');
  };
```

Imagine that the request is sent to => `https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/524/40`

I want to be able in my `action.js` to create a multiple request just adding a date parameter at the end of this `url`, something like:

From `https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/524/40` the request automatically has to be sent to these 3 endpoints

1. `https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/524/40/2019-08-30`,
2. `https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/524/40/2019-09-30`
3. `https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/524/40/2019-10-30`

My question is how can i send these multiple request in my `action.js`? How can i make an array with these 3 urls from the user action when he selects a team in my dropdown?

This is how my `getStats` it should be doing

```
export function getStats(league, team, type) {
  return function(dispatch) {

    let URLs= ["https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/524/40/2019-08-30",
              "https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/524/40/2019-09-30",
              "https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/524/40/2019-10-30"]

    const getAllData = (URLs) => {
      return Promise.all(URLs.map(fetchData));
    }

    const fetchData = (URL) => {
      return axios
        .get(URL)
        .then(res => { ......
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: the previous answer which has been deleted was almost correct

Comment: Looks straightforward. You need to implement rules for generating the three date strings. Only you know how to do that. We don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
const url = "https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics";
let dates = ["2019-08-30", "2019-09-30", "2019-10-30"]

const getAllData = (dates, i) => {
  return Promise.all(dates.map(x => url + '/' + league + '/' + team + '/' + x).map(fetchData));
}

const fetchData = (URL) => {
  return axios
    .get(URL)
    .then(res => {
```